# Laravel request function make error on route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have request function inside DashboardController to consuming my own API.

```
public function index()
{
    $total_student = $this->student();
    $total_teacher = $this->teacher();
    return view('dashboard.index', compact(
        'total_student', 
        'total_teacher'
    ));
}

function student() 
{
    $request = Request::create('/api/student', 'GET');
    $response = app()->handle($request);
    return $response->getData()->total;
}

function teacher() 
{
    $request = Request::create('/api/teacher', 'GET');
    $response = app()->handle($request);
    return $response->getData()->total;
}
```

Everything was ok, but I realize when I use **{{ route('dashboard') }}** on view it show wrong url **http://localhost/web/dashboard** where it should be **http://api.local/web/dashboard** and when I try use **{{ Request::segment(2) }}** it shows **'teacher'** later I realize it comes from the teacher function on **DashboardController** which has request on it. When I remove that function teacher and student, **{{ route('dashboard') }}** show normal : **http://api.local/web/dashboard**

Why request function in controller affect route? and how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1.) To change the app url you can do this inside the `.env` file by changing `APP_URL` from `http://localhost` to `http://api.local`

2.) The reason you are seeing `teacher` after using `{{ Request::segment(2) }}` is because your second `url "path"` is actually `teacher`. For example, if you have an url of `/api/test/hello` then second segment would be `test`, third segment would be `hello`, first segment would be `api` and so on.

Comment: It does http://api.local on ,env and route is Route group inside namespace web, Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard')->middleware('auth'); Page url is http://api.local/web/dashboard

Comment: what confusing me is why request on controller function make echo route on view given wrong name, it should be api.local/web/dashboard when I call route('dashboard') on view. when I remove or didn't use that request function, call route is normal

Comment: Tbh I think you should not call another `Request` to your `API` but rather expose your `function which returns data for API` to your `DashboardController` to `index` function and use the function instead of making an expensive operation

Comment: That make sense, I new in Laravel. I thought consuming my own API will be more efficient, So the request function already has API Route. And laravel read the Request call, so that's why when using Request::segment() Laravel read api/teacher instead of the url of current page.Thank you.